# using retrofit (@Path) with mvc?

Tags: android, model-view-controller, retrofit

I'm using retrofit 1.9 in MVC. I have this :

```
@GET("/albums/2/photos")
void getPhotosId(Callback<String> photos);
```

I want to make that number "2" between albums and photos as query parameter.
I do know how to do it in MVC.

Photos Controller :

```
        mApiManager.getPhotosApi().getPhotosId(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void success(String s, Response response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "JSON :: " + s);
            //Log.d(TAG, "OBJECT:: " + s);
            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(s);

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    Photos photo = new Photos.Builder()
                            .setPhotoTitle(object.getString("title"))
                            .build();

                    mListener.onFetchProgress(photo);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                mListener.onFetchFailed();
            }

            mListener.onFetchComplete();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error :: " + error.getMessage());
            mListener.onFetchComplete();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Google search, 1 minute. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-optional-path-parameters

Comment: I don't think MVC has any relevance in this question...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
@GET(albums/{id}/photos")
Call<String> getPhotosId(@Path("id") int id);
```